# .NET Framework 4 installation in silent mode

Tags: .net, installation, nsis

Can anyone explain how to make silent (without any user interface) install of .NET 4? It looks like .NET installer ignores any switches from this article and show interface always.
.NET Framework 4 installer is packed by NSIS.

Comment: To me the questions fits the topic. From http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : it is about "* software tools commonly used by programmers; and is * a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". It does not match any of the 6 exclusion cases. One might argue it's more a matter of deploying rather than programming. When some StackExchange site is devoted to deployment we'll move the question.  Until then I claim it fits the topic.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
dotnetfx40x86.exe /q
```

should do the trick.

[.NET Framework Deployment Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee942965%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Can I use this command in NSIS script?

Comment: Thanks. It's work `ExecWait "$INSTDIR\dotNet.exe /passive"`

Comment: Wow, `/q` is so quiet that I thought it did not even work.  Really nothing visible happens and the command prompt goes back immediately.  If you run the installer again quickly without `/q`, it complains one installer is already running, as task manager confirms. Very useful link in answer.

Comment: There is a security warning dialog that I can not prevent it. How to suppress it? I'm calling .NET 4.6.1 installer from another older C# app that is running as administrator.

Answer (score 5):

It may not be picking up your locale, try:

```
dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe /q /norestart /LCID xxxx
```

But as Mr. Piras says, look at the MS guide